# XMLA Cube Synchronization location

Tags: synchronization, location, ssas, cube, xmla

I have the following script to synchronize my OLAP cube. It works fine but it stores data in default location at my destination server. I know the **< Locations >** tag can be used to specify the location of the destination.

Can anyone cite an example of how I can use this tag and the format of the path to specify?

```
<Synchronize xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Source>
        <ConnectionString>Provider=MSOLAP.5;Data Source=172.16.203.1;ConnectTo=11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=CUBE_NAME</ConnectionString>
        <Object>
            <DatabaseID>DATABASE_NAME</DatabaseID>
        </Object>
    </Source>
    <SynchronizeSecurity>IgnoreSecurity</SynchronizeSecurity>
    <ApplyCompression>true</ApplyCompression>
</Synchronize>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set non-default locations when you are deploying your SSAS DB structure to the destination server. Syncing it afterwards will fill the SSAS DB with data from the remote location; the metadata of the local SSAS DB (and storage paths are part of this metadata) cannot be changed during sync.